# search profiles between two ranges

Tags: python, django

i want to get all the profile between the given two ages.  Example "from age:20 and to age:30"
In my model instead of age , i saved the date of birth of the user.Here i need to convert that date of birth to age and want to get the profiles between the given ages.If the question is not correct please help me to correct the question.

**models.py**

```
class profiles(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    birthday =  models.DateField(null=True)

    def age(self):
        return int((datetime.date.today() - self.birthday).days / 365.25  )
    age = property(age)
```

**views.py**

```
def search_results(request):
            from_age = form.cleaned_data['from_age']
            to_age = form.cleaned_data['to_age']
            query_set = profiles.objects.filter(gender=gender)
            if from_age < to_age:
                query_set = query_set.filter(
                    age__gte=from_age,
                    age__lte=to_age  
                )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) lookup:

```
import datetime

def search_results(request):
    from_age = form.cleaned_data['from_age']
    to_age = form.cleaned_data['to_age']

    now = datetime.date.today()
    from_date = datetime.date(now.year-int(to_age), now.month, now.day)
    to_date = datetime.date(now.year-int(from_age), now.month, now.day)

    query_set = profiles.objects.filter(gender=gender,
                                        birthday__range=(from_date, to_date))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't filter on a property.

You should do it the other way round: convert the ages into dates, and filter on that.